# How can i get HEADER in my ESB i am using following property, its not not working

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am getting the data from mobile client they are sending data in JSON as well as sending some values as HEADER to WSO2ESB i am getting normal values using this property

```
 <property name="asset" expression="//asset/text()" scope="default"/>
```

but how can i get HEADER in my ESB i am using this property its not not working

```
 <property name="username" expression="get-property('transport', 'Accept')"/>
```

how it will work will you revert me as soon as

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

if what you are trying to access is 'username', the configuration should be:

```
<property name="some_name_here" expression="get-property('transport', 'username')"/>
```